# Getting NULL in template - OpenCart 2.0

Tags: php, oop, opencart2.x

I am trying to render `product_list.tpl` file in `home.tpl` but it's giving me `NULL`

Controller File:

```
/controller/product/product_list.php
```

Code:

```
class ControllerProductProductList extends Controller {
    public function index() {

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        $filter_data = array(
                'filter_tag'          => 'featured',
                'limit'               => 9
            );
        $data['results'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);
        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/productlist.tpl')) {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/productlist.tpl', $data));
        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/common/productlist.tpl', $data));
        }
    }
}
```

Template to render

```
/template/product/productlist.tpl
```

Code:

```
<?php var_dump($results); ?>
<h2>Product are here</h2>
```

Then adding this line in `home.php` controller

`$data['special_mod'] = $this->load->controller('product/product_list');`

and printing `$special_mod` in `common/home.tpl` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `/controller/product/product_list.php`

the method `$this->response->setOutput` doesn't just return the value but send the user to the different page while what I wanted was to just output the `productlist.tpl` as string so for that I had to replace the code

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/productlist.tpl')) {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/productlist.tpl', $data));
        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/common/productlist.tpl', $data));
        }
```

with

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/productlist.tpl')) {
            return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/productlist.tpl', $data);
        } else {
            return $this->load->view('default/template/common/productlist.tpl', $data);
        }
```